# Where is the build instantly option for Builder Pro on xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite Battle Royale, all of the of the good console players use the Builder Pro settings or something similar. All of these players build very quickly, and I have heard them mention the Build Instantly setting for Builder Pro. This setting makes it so that once you go into build mode, and change to your selected building type (Stairs, Ramps etc...) it builds it automatically. I have looked for this setting, and I can't seem to find it. Does anybody know where to find this setting?

> CONTROL OPTIONS,
>   Edit Mode Aim Assist - Off
>   Turbo Building - On
>   Controller Edit Hold Time - 0.12  Builder
>   Pro: Build Immediately - On
> <sub>*-
>   [Best xbox one Fortnite controller settings from Gronky - KeenGamer](https://www.keengamer.com/article/20653_best-xbox-one-fortnite-controller-settings-from-gronky)*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the settings page, here's a screenshot I took of it.[image: Fortnite Settings Screenshot]
 I took this from a YT video so here's the link to it: [NEW INSTANT BUILD, FASTER EDITING & BUILD SENSITIVITY! Best Fortnite Console Settings & Sensitivity - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cRVyjCMQL0). So I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: THat is not you streaming ;)